# How to get the name of foreign_key column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3 and I have a simple model

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end
```

I am doing some meta programming and I need to know the name of the foreign_key in the comments table.

In the above case the answer is

```
post_id
```

However it could be anything since user can do configurations.

Assuming that you have access to both classes Post and Comment how would you get the name of the foreign_key ?

**Update:** After some testing this is what I got.

```
> User.reflections[:phone_numbers].instance_variable_get('@primary_key_name')
 => "user_id"
```

Above solution is for

```
class User
  has_many :phone_numbers
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know the name of the foreign_key in the comments table.
>
> how would you get the name of the foreign_key ?

Try this:

```
. rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
irb(main):001:0> "Post".foreign_key
=> "post_id"
```

Here is the complete [Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/foreign_key). Let me know if it works for you. I haven't tried this on custom foreign key though. Hope this helps.