# Ascertain a Rails association's foriegn_key at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations

I have a number of Rails models, each of which `has_one :myobj`. I'd like to be able to determine at runtime, what the foreign key is for each of those associations. Is this possible?

I am not trying to duplicate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541794/how-to-get-the-name-of-foreign-key-column). I want the foreign key from a specific model's viewpoint, not the default foreign key for a given mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the method [reflect_on_association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association).

On a model that looks like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :myobj, foreign_key:'myobj_id', class_name:'Bar'
end
```

Running the method gives me this:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > pp Foo.reflect_on_association(:myobj)
#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x96669f4
 @active_record=
  Foo(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime),
 @collection=false,
 @macro=:has_one,
 @name=:myobj,
 @options={:foreign_key=>"myobj_id", :class_name=>"Bar"},
 @plural_name="myobjs">
```